# Smoothness of the moduli space of principal G-bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve over the complex numbers.

Question: When the moduli space of principal $G-$bundles over $X$ is smooth Fano of Picard rank one ?

Comment: I suppose you mean the moduli space of semi-stable bundles, for $G$ semi-simple, and $g(X)>1$? Essentially never. For instance for $G=\operatorname{SL}(n) $, the moduli space is smooth only when $g(X)=n=2$.

Comment: What about in more general situation when $G$ is not semi simple ?

Comment: Like what? If $G$ has a homomorphism to $\mathbb{G}_m$, the moduli space is not of finite type.